# Limit SFTP user access to specified directory

Tags: 14.04, ssh, chroot, openssh, sftp

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 server installed with open ssh.  I'd like to configure sftp for customers to be able to download files only.  In other words, I put files in a directory that they are jailed to.  I need to make sure they can only access the directory with their file(s) and nothing else.

Originally I was going to use vsftpd, but someone told me that sftp is the better option.  If there's some documentation on what I need that would be great.

I need help with the following:

1. How to configure sftp
2. How to set up user accounts and use them for sftp
3. How to set accounts to jail

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Settings for `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -f AUTH -l VERBOSE
UsePAM yes
Match group sftp
  ChrootDirectory %h
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  AllowTcpForwarding no
```

create group sftp:

```
groupadd sftp
```

Create directory

```
sudo mkdir /ftpusers
sudo mkdir /ftpusers/HomeFolder
```

Create user directly with new sftp group attached:

```
sudo useradd -d /ftpusers/HomeFolder -m UserName -g sftp -s /bin/false
sudo passwd UserName
```

set permissions for use with ssh for sftp:

```
chown root:root /ftpusers/HomeFolder
chmod 755 /ftpusers/HomeFolder
```

restart service:

```
service ssh restart
```

Note, the home folder for the new sftp user has to be given root owner.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!  Not sure why, but when I try to create a user directly to the group.  I'm getting the following error... useradd: cannot create directory /ftpusers/HomeFolder

Comment: Run first `sudo mkdir /ftpusers`, then `sudo mkdir /ftpusers/HomeFolder`

Comment: Thank you.  Ok, next problem... When I try to set permissions for use with ssh for sftp with chown root:root HomeFolder I get chown: cannot access ‘HomeFolder’: No such file or directory

Comment: `chown root:root /ftpusers/HomeFolder` and `chmod 755 /ftpusers/HomeFolder`

Comment: `UsePAM yes` ruins everything for me and causes "connection refused". Not sure why, but commenting that line out makes everything work perfectly.

Comment: Note on directory creating; Just provide -p to mkdir, as "mkdir -p /a/long/path/to/some/folder" to create every req. subfolder as well.

Comment: I followed these directions for my 14.04.1 LTS server and I'm unable to log in. Connection refused for SFTP but listens for FTP.

Comment: @pzkpfw @israelj I experienced the same behavior and found out that by default, the lines `UsePAM yes` and `Subsystem sftp internal-sftp` are already to be found i the config file. If you write them double it will trigger some kind of error I would assume and as a consequence you can't ssh in. It help for me to let the default lines remain and only add the group match block. (Late answer but it could be useful for future debugging for others)

Comment: No success. The message I receive from the SFTP server is `... Broken pipe. Connection closed`