# How to lock user to directory?

Tags: 16.04, users, adduser

I created new user

```
adduser david
```

Now I have problem. When I login with this user via WinSCP FTP manager, default login directory is `/home/david/`. I need change for this user default direcory to `/var/www/web/css/` and lock him into this folder.

How?

Comment: Possibly related: [Limit SFTP user access to specified directory](http://askubuntu.com/questions/598870/limit-sftp-user-access-to-specified-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit this in
/etc/passwd

The fields in /etc/passwd are separated by :
The last but on field is the user's home directory.

Just make sure you do not introduce any extra spaces.

Comment: I want lock user `david` into `/var/www/web/css/`. I want block `..` (folder up) for user `david`. Is it possible?

Comment: This not working how I want

Comment: @Dave please see the link I posted under your question

Comment: Please explain what you want.

Comment: The link provided above by steeldriver should answer this issue.